# Detect if link is a download in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, download, cross-browser

I am working on a PHP application that can take a couple seconds to load the next page. In order to prevent users from spam-clicking buttons (and to let them know the page is loading) while the next page loads, I have implemented a page-loading spinner that covers the page:

```
// Assume all internal links start with "http://www.example.com"
$('a[href*="http://www.example.com"]').on("click", function () {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  if (!href || href[0] === "#") {
    location.hash = href;// set that hash
    return;
  } else {
    location = href;
    $(".loading-spinner").fadeIn(100, function () {
        setTimeout(function(){ $(".loading-spinner").fadeOut(200); }, 10000); // 10 second loading maximum
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

In the event of a link starting a file download, I would like to fade out the `.loading-spinner` as soon as the download is detected.

Is there some way to detect if the link has triggered a download vs. loading a page using javascript/jQuery or do I need to specially identify all download links (using a special class, etc.)?

Comment: Are you using `download Attribute` ?

Comment: not at the moment, but that is probably what I would do instead of using a "download" class, etc. Generally speaking, I don't know what the content-type is.

Comment: To be frank, Preveen has provided descent answer but if you are suppose to deal with `download` attribute, things will be easier to manipulate..

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, unfortunately I work with a team who I can guarantee won't want to go back and add the `download` attribute to all download links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire an AJAX request to the URL and get the content type using the [`getResponseHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader) function:

```
$.get(url, function (response, status, xhr) {
  if (xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type").indexOf("text") > -1)
    // Text based stuff.
  else
    // Download based stuff. (eg., application/pdf, etc.)
});
```

*More Info:*

> The **`XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader()`** method returns the string containing the text of the specified header, or `null` if either the response has not yet been received or the header doesn't exist in the response. If there are multiple response headers with the same name, then their values are returned as a single concatenated string, where each value is separated from the previous one by a pair of comma and space. The `getResponseHeader()` method returns the value as a UTF byte squence.

Comment: This method would require submitting two requests, correct? It's probably best to just find and add the `download` attribute to all download links.